# Может ли вложенный, внутренний класс или интерфейс быть раннер-классом?

Tags: java, классы, интерфейс, вложенные-классы

Можете пояснить. Может ли вложенный, внутренний класс или интерфейс быть раннер-классом. На практике вроде только во внешнем классе можно реализовать раннер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве примера можно привести интерфейс [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html).

Создаем статический метод:

```java
public static void test(Runnable runnable) {
    System.out.println("Start");
    runnable.run();
    System.out.println("End");
}
```

Затем вызываем его из метода `main`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(() -> {
        System.out.println("Do something");
    });
}
```

Вывод:

```
Start
Do something
End
```

Такой код будет выполнен в текущем потоке. Для многопоточного режима см. класс [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html).

Создаем класс, имплементирующий интерфейс `Runnable`:

```java
public class Runner implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Do something");
    }
}
```

Затем создаем и запускаем отдельный поток:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runner());
    thread.start();
}
```

То же самое можно проще:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("Do something");
    }).start();
}
```

Вывод:

```
Do something
```